# application loader　90125エラーでビルドできません

Tags: ios, monaca

monacaでiosアプリを開発、いったん申請が通ったものです。
バージョンアップしようと思い、Application Loader 3.0　でビルドしようとしていますが、下記90125Error　というのが出てビルドできません。
何が原因でしょうか。

ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker.

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。理由はわからないのですが、X-CODEを最新(６．２以上、現在6.3.2です）にバージョンアップしたら無事ビルドできました。